# users overview tab error in phpMyAdmin for WordPress username

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

When I am logged in to phpMyAdmin I try to view my users tab and it gives me the following error message: "not enough privilege to view users" - I am logged in as the main user of my account and I already created a database, but I can't find the user name to my WordPress PHP login and I need to access the users tab but I can't any step by step guide how to get around this error or work this out?

Comment: Your mysql login credentials are in `wp-config.php` in the root of your WordPress install.

Comment: I am logged in to my DB the problem is accesing the Users tab I can't...

Comment: Are you trying to access your WordPress website login username?

Comment: yes lol and my user and password should be in either those tabs.. or is there anywhere else I can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not seem to have grant or read access to these accounts , see the original phpMyAdmin code at line 2615 :

```
/**
 * Get HTML error for View Users form
 * For non superusers such as grant/create users
 *
 * @return string $html_output
 */
function PMA_getHtmlForViewUsersError()
{
    return Message::error(
        __('Not enough privilege to view users.')
    )->getDisplay();
}
```

are you logged in as a super user who has access to all the databases(not just one) and the users ?

Update :
Now that I see, I think you are looking for your WordPress user name so that you can login with it, if so instead of looking at the users tab, look at wp_user or some similar table within the database

Comment: I am sorry I am learning my ways with phpMyAdmin I logged in through my database manager from my web host. how do I log in as a super user after I am in my database...?

Comment: OK WordPress user & database user are two different things, if you are looking for database users, try creating one from your current database login or get the super user login, also look at my updated answer

Comment: I am really trying to log in to my Wordpress but it says I have the wrong password when i tried to reset it they do not send me an email to the specified account nor I can find it in the user tab of the database because it don't allow me. then how do I get the super user login.. which I am guessing I am missing something here.. thanks

Comment: Ok I see, now can you see a table within your database called wp_user? If u can access it, then go to that table & find your username there

Comment: I said database table not php files

Comment: that's in my DB Im sorry yes I do see the wp_users but it has the same username and password as to log in to the phpMyAdmin I tried that and still get that wrong password error.. if I delete it what would happen? or can I create another one there..?

Comment: Ok fine now that you can see it, you can reset password from here, remember the password is encrypted so simply deleting or entering would not work. Soon I will send you a link which will let you generate an encrypted password

Comment: oooh nice got it... thanks I will wait.. appreciate it

Comment: so with that encrypted pass. I should be able to log in to my WP right?

Comment: no worries I got it all I had to do was set the password to MD5 and it would make it encrypted and let me access the WP oh Thank YOU!!!! for all the help